# Problema al guardar php

Tags: php

estoy haciendo una funcionde fecha y hora, la cual tiene que validar que no se esten repitiendo la hora del mismo dia, o sea, que no debe de haber dos turnos en la hora 18:09 del dia 10/11/2021, pero si puede haber otro turno en una hora diferente del mismo dia. El problema que tengo es que me salta el mensaje "error" cuando selecciono otras fechas

Les paso el codigo:

Codigo de la funcion:

```
 public static function validarHora($Fecha, $Hora){
       $database = new MySQL();
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM turno WHERE fecha ='{$Fecha}' AND hora='{$Hora}'";
        //echo $sql;
        //exit;
        $datos = $database->consultar($sql);

       $respuesta="";
       if($datos->num_rows == 0){
            $repuesta = 0;
           // echo $respuesta;
            //exit;
        }else{
            $repuesta= 1;
           // echo $respuesta;
           // exit;
        }
        return $respuesta;
    }
```

Codigo del procesar :

```
$servicio = $_POST['cboServicio'];
$paciente = $_POST["cboPaciente"];
$fecha = $_POST["txtFecha"];
$hora = $_POST["txtHora"];



$validar = turno::validarHora($fecha,$hora);
//Si la hora no es igual a otra hora, que se guarde
if($validar == 0){
    $turno = new turno();
    $turno->setIdPaciente($paciente);
    $turno->setFecha($fecha);
    $turno->setHora($hora);
    //$turno = turno::validarHora($hora);
    //$turno = turno::validarFecha($fecha);
    
    $turno->guardar();
    
    $idTurno = $turno->getIdTurno();
    
    foreach ($servicio as $servicios){
    
        $turnoServicio = new turnoServicio;
        $turnoServicio->setIdTurno($idTurno);
        $turnoServicio->setIdServicio($servicios);
        $turnoServicio->guardar();
    }

    header("location: listado.php");
}else{
     //Sino que tire :
    header("location: nuevo.php?error=horarioRepetido");
    
}
```

Comment: Creo que falta que indiques cual es el error que te esta mostrando.

Comment: En `validarHora()` pon un `var_dump($datos);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: El error que tenia es que no me estaba guardando en listado, ya lo pude solucionar, tenia problemas de caché. De todas formas muchas gracias